# HttpWebRequest double expected network traffic

Tags: c#, utf-8, httpwebrequest

I'm using the following snippet to send a HTTP request.

```
byte[] requestData = new byte[41943040]; 
.... fill requestData with some data
requestLength = 41883480;

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Credentials = credentials;
request.Method = "POST";
using (Stream requestSteam = request.GetRequestStream())
{
  requestSteam.Write(requestData, 0, requestLength);
}
Console.WriteLine(request.ContentLength);
.... get response and do something with it
```

The value output to console is 41,884,294. Therefore i would expect the outbound network traffic generated by this operation to be roughly 40MB. I have checked using three different methods (two locally installed network monitoring applications and one on my router) and found that the outbound traffic is over 80MB.

Is this expected behavior?

If I only have 40MB of data to send, how would I acheive only sending 40MB rather than 80?

Edit: It might be worth mentioning that this is HTTPS, however my understanding of the HTTPS handshaking suggests that the overhead for this should be small.

Edit2: I've now switched to using TCPClient & SSLStream and this is no longer occurring. It's a bit more work but I'm now only sending the expected 40MB of data.

Comment: What happens with 30k bytes?

Comment: Misread this and tried with 30MB. 60MB was sent. I Might not be able to accurately measure with only 30KB.

Comment: Why does your `requestData` contain `41943040` but you are actually writing `41883480` bytes of data to the request stream? Surely this cannot explain the double difference but I was just wondering about this mismatch.

Comment: The upper limit on the length of `requestData` is `41943040`, the actual amount needed to be sent will vary and is defined by `requestLength`. The array is instantiated once, and the values are overwritten as necessary.